# div not visible in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to show a div using the css `display` property.

The contents of `#divbar` and `#divline` are set dynamically using AJAX.

This code works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 8 I'm unable to see the content of `#divbar` even though the *toggle* button works perfectly.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="divline" style="float:left;">
    <div id="jqChart2" class="charts"></div>
</div>

<div id="divbar" style="float:left">
    <div id="jqChartb2" class="charts"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#toggle_button1").click(function(){
    $("#toggle_button1").css({'display':'none'});
    $("#toggle_button2").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#divline").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#divbar").css({'display':'none'});
});

$("#toggle_button2").click(function(){
    $("#toggle_button2").css({'display':'none'});
    $("#toggle_button1").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#divline").css({'display':'none'});
    $("#divbar").css({'display':'block'});
});
```

**CSS :**

```
#toggle_button1{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}
#toggle_button2{
    display:none;
    width:100px;
}
#divline{
    display:block;
}
#divbar{
    display:none;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: FYI, jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` are shortcuts for `.css({'display':'none'})` and `.css({'display':'block'})`.

Comment: i am not able to see the contents of #divbar.

Comment: I don't see anything conceptually wrong with your code.  Do you see any script errors?  Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle so we can see what is actually happening?  Are you installing your click event handlers AFTER the toggle_button objects exist?

Comment: actually its workin well in mozilla and chrome.But when i try it in IE * its not showing output

Comment: where's the AJAX code? likely a problem there like a trailing comma which always fails in IE but other browsers are more forgiving. Look in IE developer console for script errrors thrown. Also validate returned html, IE not very tolerant when html is invalid

Comment: Can you see my answer ???

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work in ie8. it totally works in my test, but it's not relying on ajax call. i'm going to assume that's where your problem is. without posting more, i doubt this is going to get solved. http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ie8test.html

Answer (score 0):

I think in following code:

```
<div id="divbar" style="float:left">
<div id="jqChartb2" class="charts" >      </div>
</div>
```

problem is related with

```
<div id="jqChartb2" class="charts" >      </div>
```

Please try another content instead of it
For example :

```
<div id="divbar" style="float:left">
Test
</div>
```

Comment: ...i tried your solution but it didnt help me..when i set css property as "block" of both i am getting the results but at first time it shows both content

Answer (score 0):

Check you have  Enable JavaScript on IE8??

try below way in your ie8 browser

```
Click ‘Tools’ on the menu bar’
Select ‘Internet Options’
Click the ‘Security’ tab
Click the ‘Custom Level’ button
Scroll to the ‘Scripting’ section 
Select ‘Enable’ to enable whichever JavaScript activities you want to work.
```